# WebApplicationInitializer not reached

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm building a BlogPost for a school project with Spring. I can reach my index.jsp but when I map to other controllers I get a 404. When I set a breakpoint in my WebApplicationInitializer in the @OnStartUp method it never gets reached. Does anybody know What I'm missing here? Thanks!

Here's my code:

WebapplicationInitializer:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

    private WebApplicationContext getContext(){
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("be.kdg.BlogPostSpringMVC.configuration");
        return context;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>be.kdg.BlogPostWebApp</groupId>
<artifactId>BlogPostWebApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>be.kdg.spring.BlogPost</groupId>
        <artifactId>BlogPost</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And pom.xml of the injected BlogPost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>be.kdg.spring.BlogPost</groupId>
<artifactId>BlogPost</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What container are you using and at which version?

Comment: Do not be excessively confident in breakpoint in initializing code ... Spring framework is known to suspend breakpoints during its initialization phase (at least on Netbeans) ... Good old logging is the only foolproof method to know if a method has been called.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and I've tried logging but no result..

What do you mean by container?

Answer (score 1):

Change `context.setConfigLocation("be.kdg.BlogPostSpringMVC.configuration")` to `context.scan("be.kdg.BlogPostSpringMVC.configuration")`.

setConfigLocation() is used to specify the location of the spring configuration file.

Comment: I've tried context.scan("be.kdg.BlogPostSpringMVC.configuration") and I've tried context.setConfigLocation("be.kdg.BlogPostSpringMVC.configuration.AppContext"). Still no result...

Comment: And I've tried context.setConfigLocation("be/kdg/BlogPostSpringMVC/configuration/AppContext.java")
Still no result.. IntelliJ does recognize the path so I think this should be ok

Comment: Just want to make sure, have you annotated the class with @Configuration annotation?

Comment: I had the AppContext class annotated with @Configuration, didn't know I had to annotate the WebApplicationInitializer as @ Configuration too. I did it now but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Have you added `<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>` in web.xml?

Comment: I'm not using web.xml file but am using annotationbased config file which extends WebMVCConfigerAdapter. And I have added a contextLoaderListener in the WebApplicationInitializer. Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: Can you invoke `context.refresh();` and try, after calling the `scan()` method?

Comment: Did you mean this? 
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.scan("be.kdg.BlogPostSpringMVC.configuration");
        context.refresh();

Still no result..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64416/discussion-between-mithun-and-maarten-meeusen).

Comment: Since the `WebApplicationInitializer` looks good, there could be problem with the url-pattern used in `@RequestMapping`. Could you check if the url in `@RequestMapping` is starting with an `/`?

Comment: For example: this is the header of the loginController:
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.do")
@SessionAttributes("userBean")
public class LoginController {

Answer (score 0):

your **pom.xml** file is missing the `dependency:spring-context-support`, that solved the issue for me